# Using ExecuteCommand in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to execute the statements on my DB:

```
/*Disable Constraints & Triggers*/
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'

/*Perform delete operation on all table for cleanup*/
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; DELETE ?'

/*Enable Constraints & Triggers again*/
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL'

/*Reset Identity on tables with identity column*/
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'IF OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(''?''), ''TableHasIdentity'') = 1 BEGIN DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'',RESEED,0) END'
```

I have my LINQ datacontext:

```
   public static bool ClearDatabase()
      {
          GetContext().ExecuteCommand("");
      }
```

The part that was not clear in MSDN docs is... should I be running each statement as a separate command or make a big long string to execute?

Should I also be keeping the exec statements?

Also, if anyone knows a better way to clear a database with LINQ, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can test if you can execute multiple statements in one command. You can set a SQL profiler for that and see the SQL query that was generated by LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Execute` simply executes it; the inside is entirely opaque (apart from `{0}` etc, which is used to denote parameters - i.e. `{0}` becomes something like `@_p0`, with values supplied from the `params` array). As such, as long as your TSQL is valid (and doesn't include `GO` etc) then it should work fine. It certainly doesn't care that the TSQL is long. But: try it.

However, personally I'd say that running this from a data-context is risky, as the data-context may have cached state which could really confuse things. Personally I'd run it from ADO.NET directly (or via a helper like "dapper"). But I suppose it'll work fine if you dispose+discard (and perhaps re-create) the data-context immediately after doing this.